# Using zero loss error for specific label

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm training a dataset that has 16 labels as output. When finishing training I would like to train another dataset, with the weights of the first one, that has only a subset of the labels 14 of 16. A friend told me I have to set a zero loss error on those missing labels.

I'm using tensorflow and keras as high level API. Any tips how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In keras each model has a layers attribute in which you can reuse the layers for rebuilding the model. Reusing those layers will result in weight sharing.

There are two solution to your problem:

1. In your second model build a new output layer with the right amount of output neurons which don't have weight sharing. (Not exactly what you want but easy to implement)
   Also you might want to [freeze](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers) the previous layer depending on your usecase.
2. Build a custom loss function. This will heavily depend on which loss function you use at the moment. But the trick is to slice your predictions, e.g. y_pred[:, :-2](the first dimension is the batch size).

I personally wouldn't recommend the second approach. If you use activation function like softmax the weights corresponding to the the unused output neurons might still be updated.

Also there is the possibility to somehow get the weights of the last layer, slice them and rebuilding a new layer with the right output. But this could get really ugly.